# CIS hardening script for windows 2016 server in GCP

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, ansible, windows-server-2016

I want to perform hardening in my Windows server 2016 which is hosted under a GCP account. Anyone has any Ansible or other scripts to perform CIS hardening level on the above spec?

Actually, I'm a newbie in this area and your recommendation would be grateful.

Awaiting expert commands?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Github posts, seems to be what you are looking for. [HardeningKitty and Windows 10 Hardening](https://github.com/0x6d69636b/windows_hardening). Even though the titel says windows 10, in the article there's a full list of "supported" systems including Windows Server 2016.